# Simple, Free PHP Email to SMS Solution?

Tags: php, email, sms

I think I found a way to get around not knowing a phone's carrier when sending an sms message via email.

It is: just send the text to every single major email (there's 5 or 6).

Is there anything wrong with this? Would the carrier's block me eventually?

Comment: There's a lot more than 5 or 6 http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_SMS_gateways

Comment: That's worldwide. He's probably referring to the US, where the top 5 or 6 should cover most of the market these days.

Answer (score 3):

I wouldn't recommend that approach - the carriers do monitor their email and web gateways, and you'll certainly be blocked once you reach any significant volume.

If this is for a commercial project, there are pretty cheap solutions available to look up a carrier by phone number. Check out [Neustar](http://www.neustar.biz/) or [Sybase 365](http://www.sybase.com/mobileservices/) (disclaimer: I worked for Inphomatch/Mobile 365 before they were bought by Sybase) - there are others. It'll probably cost your a few cents per lookup and prices usually go down with volume.

Comment: Why would you pay a few cents per lookup, when you can pay a few cents per SMS on a real gateway?/

Comment: Lookup prices are probably lower than delivery prices on gateways, since those have to pay for the lookups too and will include that in their per-message cost. However, this question is about email delivery, for which you don't need a gateway. Carriers are still likely to block emails above a certain threshold, so a gateway might be the way to go.